# useEffect and useState from Child to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have an issue with my project.
I need to pass the state of a countdown Child component to a Parent component, to make the Parent component visible or not if the time is 0.

this is my countdown component

```
import { Typography, Paper, Grid } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const formatTime = (time) => {
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60);

  if (minutes <= 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds <= 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  return minutes + ':' + seconds;
};

function CountDown(props) {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(props.seconds);
  const [onTime, setOnTime] = useState(true);
  const timertId = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    timertId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timertId.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (countdown <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timertId.current);
      setOnTime(false);
    }
  }, [countdown]);

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper elevation={0} variant='outlined' square>
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            Timer:
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper
          elevation={0}
          variant='outlined'
          square
          sx={{ bgcolor: 'lightblue' }}
        >
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            {formatTime(countdown)}
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default CountDown;
```

I want to pass the OnTime state to the Parent component:

```
export default function QuestionCard() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest: getQuestions } = useAxios();
  const { sendRequest: getAnswers } = useAxios();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setValue(true);
  };

  const handleSelectedItem = (index) => {
    setClickedIndex(index);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
      const loadedQuestions = [];

      for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
        loadedQuestions.push({
          id: questionKey,
          id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
          tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
          testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
          immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
          eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
        });
      }
      setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
    };
    getQuestions(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL_Q,
      },
      transformQuestions
    );
  }, [getQuestions]);

  let questionsTitle = questions.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
  let questionId = questions.map((element) => `${element.id}`);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            minWidth: 275,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingLeft: '50%',
            paddingBottom: '5%',
            position: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Card
            variant='outlined'
            sx={{
              minWidth: 400,
            }}
          >
            <CardContent>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                  <Typography
                    variant='h5'
                    component='div'
                    fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                  >
                    Nome Test
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <CountDown seconds={300} />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>

              <LinearProgress variant='determinate' value={1} />

              <Typography
                sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5 }}
                fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                fontWeight={'bold'}
              >
                {questionsTitle[currentQuestionIndex]}
              </Typography>

              <ButtonGroup
                fullWidth
                orientation='vertical'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 1}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(1)}
                >
                  Risposta 1
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 2}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(2)}
                >
                  Risposta 2
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 3}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(3)}
                >
                  Risposta 3
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 4}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(4)}
                >
                  Risposta 4
                </ListItemButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button onClick={goToNext} disabled={!value} variant='contained' size='small'>
                Avanti
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

The idea is that onTime is true, the QuestionCard gets rendered with question and answers, if onTime is false, it gets rendered an alert or a text. How can I pass the onTime state from Countdown to QuestionCard? Thank you

Comment: Please always trim down your code to the minimum that is necessary to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new state in your parent component and pass its setter function to the child component and now you can update a parent's state in the child component. Please check below code

Your child component

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (countdown <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timertId.current);
      setOnTime(false);
      setOnTimeFromCountdown(false);//set the value here and now you can access this value in your parent component
    }
  }, [countdown]);

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper elevation={0} variant='outlined' square>
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            Timer:
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper
          elevation={0}
          variant='outlined'
          square
          sx={{ bgcolor: 'lightblue' }}
        >
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            {formatTime(countdown)}
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default CountDown;
```

Your parent component

```
export default function QuestionCard() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest: getQuestions } = useAxios();
  const { sendRequest: getAnswers } = useAxios();
  const [onTimeFromCountdown, setOnTimeFromCountdown] = useState(true);//add this state; you can set any initial value as per your requirement

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setValue(true);
  };

  const handleSelectedItem = (index) => {
    setClickedIndex(index);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
      const loadedQuestions = [];

      for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
        loadedQuestions.push({
          id: questionKey,
          id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
          tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
          testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
          immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
          eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
        });
      }
      setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
    };
    getQuestions(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL_Q,
      },
      transformQuestions
    );
  }, [getQuestions]);

  let questionsTitle = questions.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
  let questionId = questions.map((element) => `${element.id}`);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            minWidth: 275,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingLeft: '50%',
            paddingBottom: '5%',
            position: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Card
            variant='outlined'
            sx={{
              minWidth: 400,
            }}
          >
            <CardContent>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                  <Typography
                    variant='h5'
                    component='div'
                    fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                  >
                    Nome Test
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <CountDown setOnTimeFromCountdown={setOnTimeFromCountdown} seconds={300} />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>

              <LinearProgress variant='determinate' value={1} />

              <Typography
                sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5 }}
                fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                fontWeight={'bold'}
              >
                {questionsTitle[currentQuestionIndex]}
              </Typography>

              <ButtonGroup
                fullWidth
                orientation='vertical'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 1}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(1)}
                >
                  Risposta 1
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 2}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(2)}
                >
                  Risposta 2
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 3}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(3)}
                >
                  Risposta 3
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 4}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(4)}
                >
                  Risposta 4
                </ListItemButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button onClick={goToNext} disabled={!value} variant='contained' size='small'>
                Avanti
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice here is to manage the `onTime` state in the parent, and pass the `setOnTime` function from the Parent to the `CountDown` component through the props, so it will be able to change the onTime state in the parent.

Suggestion for implementation:

```
export default function QuestionCard() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest: getQuestions } = useAxios();
  const { sendRequest: getAnswers } = useAxios();
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setValue(true);
  };

  const handleSelectedItem = (index) => {
    setClickedIndex(index);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
      const loadedQuestions = [];

      for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
        loadedQuestions.push({
          id: questionKey,
          id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
          tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
          testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
          immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
          eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
        });
      }
      setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
    };
    getQuestions(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL_Q,
      },
      transformQuestions
    );
  }, [getQuestions]);

  let questionsTitle = questions.map((element) => `${element.testo}`);
  let questionId = questions.map((element) => `${element.id}`);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            minWidth: 275,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingLeft: '50%',
            paddingBottom: '5%',
            position: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Card
            variant='outlined'
            sx={{
              minWidth: 400,
            }}
          >
            <CardContent>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                  <Typography
                    variant='h5'
                    component='div'
                    fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                  >
                    Nome Test
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <CountDown seconds={300} setOnTime={setOnTime} />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>

              <LinearProgress variant='determinate' value={1} />

              <Typography
                sx={{ mb: 1.5, mt: 1.5 }}
                fontFamily={'Roboto'}
                fontWeight={'bold'}
              >
                {questionsTitle[currentQuestionIndex]}
              </Typography>

              <ButtonGroup
                fullWidth
                orientation='vertical'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 1}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(1)}
                >
                  Risposta 1
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 2}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(2)}
                >
                  Risposta 2
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 3}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(3)}
                >
                  Risposta 3
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton
                  selected={clickedIndex === 4}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectedItem(4)}
                >
                  Risposta 4
                </ListItemButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button onClick={goToNext} disabled={!value} variant='contained' size='small'>
                Avanti
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

```
import { Typography, Paper, Grid } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const formatTime = (time) => {
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60);

  if (minutes <= 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds <= 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  return minutes + ':' + seconds;
};

function CountDown(props) {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(props.seconds);
  const timertId = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    timertId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timertId.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (countdown <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timertId.current);
      props.setOnTime(false);
    }
  }, [countdown, props.setOnTime]);

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper elevation={0} variant='outlined' square>
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            Timer:
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Paper
          elevation={0}
          variant='outlined'
          square
          sx={{ bgcolor: 'lightblue' }}
        >
          <Typography component='h6' fontFamily={'Roboto'}>
            {formatTime(countdown)}
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default CountDown;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `onTime` hook to the parent object (`QuestionCard`), and pass the setter function `setOntime` to the child.

Since you aren't using `onTime` in `CountDown`, it doesn't make sense to define it there. Using the method described above will move your state object to where it needs to be, an allow greater control by passing the setter function to where it is required.